# Air and Empty Space

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, atoms, air, gas

**Dry air contains 78.08% nitrogen, 20.95% oxygen, 0.93% argon, 0.04% carbon dioxide, and small amounts of other gases**

Which means if I were to take a differential volume dV of air, at any instant of time, then 78% of it would be occupied by N2, 21% by oxygen, 0.93% by Ar and so on.

My question is why aren't we considering the empty space? Some volume in that dV volume, will be empty, occupied by nothing. Then why some % is not stated as empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the percentage by moles, not the percentage by absolute volume. Of all the matter inside the volume that you considered, nitrogen atoms would make 78.08% of the number of atoms and so on. Since the volume of a gas at a particular temperature and pressure is proportional to the number of moles of the gas according to Avogadro's law, the percentage in terms of volume is also an equivalent representation.

But if you take a differential volume $dV$, it's improbable that you'll find any atoms in the volume. Gases have very low density, and you'll be lucky to find even a few atoms inside your differential volume. So the composition would definitely not look like the one you mentioned.

Comment: The answer is correct except that it put much emphasis on the proper volume of the molecules. One can certainly express the composition of a gas mixture in terms of volumes.

Comment: @Alchimista Yes, but since OP mentioned infinitesimal volumes, the continuum hypothesis would not be very meaningful in the case of gases. We can always express the composition of gases in terms of volumes as well provided the volumes are big enough.

Comment: Yes, basically OP asked if the matter is a continuum although knowing that it is composed at least by molecules and there is empty space in between. The point I wanted to make is that you can find a dV with right the given composition, at least doing the engineering oriented calculations that physicists and chemists do.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/123106002/MODULE%2520-%2520I/Lecture%25201.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi19OjU_aPzAhWR_XMBHaXDAOAQFnoECDUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0OhEM0Xo8_9IdGnU0RxzVf  .  I found this document stating volume and mass % of constituents in air.

Comment: @HarshitRajput The volume of the gas at a particular temperature and pressure is proportional to the number of the moles of the gas. I will rephrase my answer, so it doesn't lead to any confusion.

Comment: Oh Alright. Thanks